# iOS: Set Alternate Icon back to original

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 icons: 
Primary - the default icon 
Alt1 
Alt2

Where Alt1 & Alt2 are alternate app icons.

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(newValue.rawValue) { (error) in
       // Handle error
}
```

I can set the alternate icon just fine.
But, I am unable to switch from one of the Alternate icons back to the primary icon.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Specify nil](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname) if you want to display the app’s primary icon, which you
> declare using the CFBundlePrimaryIcon key.

```swift
try await setAlternateIconName(nil)
```